# Is there possible try to get one field on document Firestore, then add into SharedPreference for passing data in same activity?

Tags: java, android, firebase, sharedpreferences, google-cloud-firestore

[HELP]

I want to do this :

1. get one field int from my document Firestore.
2. saving value of the field in integer.
3. then add value into SharedPreferences.
4. and last, get SharedPereferences value in same activity and implement it  for limitOrder.

**This is how i get the value and adding value into shared preferences :**

```
DocumentReference kursiRef = firestoreDB.collection("dapil").document("Jatim");
            kursiRef.get()
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                DocumentSnapshot doc = task.getResult();


                                int jmlKursi = doc.getLong("jumlah_kursi").intValue();
                                SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(HasilActivity.this);
                                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                                editor.putInt("KEY_JUMLAH_KURSI", jmlKursi);
                                editor.commit();
                            } else {
                                Log.d(TAG, "Gagal mendapatkan data:  ", task.getException());
                            }

                        }
                    });
```

**this is the example of my document on firestore : 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXiNN.png)**

**and this is how i get shared preferences value and implement it for limitOrder :**

```
      SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    int jmlKursi = prefs.getInt("KEY_JUMLAH_KURSI",11); //11: default value
    mProgress.setMessage("Loading Data");
        mProgress.show();
        CollectionReference rankRef = firestoreDB.collection("pembagian");
        rankRef.orderBy("suara_rank", Query.Direction.DESCENDING).limit(jmlKursi)
```

**the issue :
limit has return 11 cause default value of shared preferences is 11.**

Comment: I see in your database that the value of `jumlah_kursi` is also `11`. What is wrong with your code? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: when i was change the default value, result of jmlKursi will return the default value not data  jumlah_kursi from database @AlexMamo

Comment: what i want to achive is, get data jumlah_kursi from my database not return default value from shared preferences